# How to calculate the time difference between start time column and end time column?

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, datediff, time-difference

I have 2 columns with start and end time values (yyyy-mm-dd ' ' hh-mm-ss 'UTC')

for example:
start time (2023-12-24 01:11:19 UTC)
end time (2023-12-24 02:12:47 UTC)

What I want to know is how do I create a new column showing the time difference between the start and end time? Would I need to remove the timezone?

I've come across DATEDIFF but every example I've seen using it have put in specific values instead of using a function to cover the whole table of values.

Comment: What are the data types for these columns? Is it VARCHAR?

Comment: @Abra TIMESTAMP

Comment: @Abra I'm using BigQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can use below (BigQuery)

```
timestamp_diff(end_time, start_time, minute)
```

See below example

```
with your_table as (
  select '2023-12-24 01:11:19 UTC' as start_time, '2023-12-24 02:12:47 UTC' as end_time
)
select start_time, end_time, 
  timestamp_diff(timestamp(end_time), timestamp(start_time), minute) as diff_minutes
from your_table
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! I ended up figuring it out before seeing your comment but thankyou for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you need to remove the 'UTC' part using the LEFT function (this works since your date is in fixed length format, then you do a DateDiff for example:

```
select DATEDIFF(mi,LEFT('2023-12-24 01:11:19 UTC',19), LEFT('2023-12-24 02:12:47 UTC',19))
```

you can substitute the string literals in above example with the column names that holds the date values

Comment: Thanks, I think I've understood most of it. What is mi? minutes?

Comment: @JakeWillMoran yes, mi is minutes. That parameter can take HH (hour), D (Day),M (month)... and so on

Comment: `DATEDIFF` doesn't actually tell you the exact *difference*, it merely counts date *boundaries*, which might not be the same.